# Can you define <col> tags (with classes) in CSS and apply them to multiple tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is it possible to define the columns for a table of a specific class and reuse it?

For example, I have two tables on a page and I want their columns to align, so currently they both have defs like:

```
<table class='grid'>
    <col class='col-name' />
    <col class="col-access-type" />
    <col class="col-auto-grant" />
    <col class="col-auto-revoke" />
    <col class="col-can-assign" />
    <col class="col-actions" />
```

but ideally I want to re-use the col tags by defining them once in say CSS so that I simply write:

```
<table class='grid'>
```

and in CSS:

```
table.grid
{
 columns: {erm ok so what is it?}
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Not in HTML and CSS, no (It wouldn't be a job for CSS anyway because what you want to do is related to content, not presentation.) It might be possible using one of the pre-compiled pseudo languages (like HAML) though - are you willing to use something like that?

Comment: Yes you can. But its a matter of what works and what does not.

Comment: @Pekka, sure HAML would keep the code DRY, and I love HAML, but alas its not possible for this project.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the answer you're looking for is CSS3`s`nth-of-type()` selector.

This would allow you to do something like this:

```
table.grid td:nth-of-type(1) { .... }
table.grid td:nth-of-type(2) { .... }
table.grid td:nth-of-type(3) { .... }
```

etc.

However, the major problem with this is that it isn't supported in IE8 or lower, so unless your user demographic is wildly different from the norm, you're not going to be able to use it.

I don't know of any other solution that will allow you to avoid repeating your column structure. Sorry.

[EDIT]

Actually, probably `nth-of-type()` would be better than `nth-child()` in this case.

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html for browser compatibility chart, and http://www.quirksmode.org/css/nthchild.html for usage (covers both `nth-of-type` and `nth-child`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bit of jQuery script to do this, so for every table with the `grid` class if applies the required classes to the cols, e.g.

```
$(function() {
    $("table.grid col:eq(0)").addClass("col-name");
    $("table.grid col:eq(1)").addClass("col-access-type");
    // etc.
});
```

Comment: It works and its DRY but its not degradable and would look pretty ugly on a js-disabled browser...